# VBA Loop through table columns names and combine data in a new sheet

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, loops

I have 2 tables on separate tabs that have a number of columns with the same names.  I'd like to combine the data for these 2 tables into a new table on a 3rd tab.

I've tried experiment with a number of ways to do this like just hard coding the column location (like A,B,C..) and manually coding in the 20 or so columns that I need to copy and paste over.  However, I'd rather run through a loop of an array of the column titles I need to copy, grab the data and append to the 3rd table. That way if the locations move it keeps working and I only have to worry about the column titles. I'm not that advanced on using arrays or working with named tables in VBA so I was hoping someone could help me out.

Example:

```
Dim arr1 As Variant
Dim vItm As Variant
Dim tbl1 As ListObject
Dim tbl2 As ListObject
Dim tbl3 As ListObject


arr1 = Array("Header1", "Header2", "Header3")
Set tbl1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
Set tbl2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table2")
Set tbl3 = Worksheets("Sheet3").ListObjects("Table3")

For Each vItm In arr1

    Set c = tbl2.ListColumns(vItm).DataBodyRange

    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        col = c.Column

          With tbl2.DataBodyRange
            tRows = .Rows.Count
            tCols = .Columns.Count
            Set CopyRng = .Range(.Cells(0, col), .Cells(tRows - 1, col))

          End With

          Set Dest = tbl1.HeaderRowRange.Find(vItm, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

          MsgBox Dest.Address

    Else
        MsgBox "Header not found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next vItm
```

For each column title in the array look in Table1 and copy all data below and paste in the corresponding column title in Table3.  Do this with all array items. Then for each column title in the array look in Table2 and copy all data below and paste in the corresponding column title in Table3 below the data that came from Table1.

Appreciate any help here.  Thanks!

Comment: You can use Find() to locate each of the column headers, so I would start with that, try writing some code, then post back when/if you run into a specific problem.  Right now your question is a little too broad - the approach you describe is reasonable, so try making a start.

Comment: @TimWilliams I updated the code in my original post to give an update of where I got to on this.  Right now I'm up to the point where I think I've got the correct data being copied on each loop and the correct destination column in the table I'll be consolidating data. I'm kind of stuck now cause it not clear how I should offset the destination cell to append the data below the last active row in the destination table. And then I would still need to loop through the 3rd table and do the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've resolved most of my issues references the correct tables and data to copy and move over. I will post the finished code in my original question. However now I am having issues with some variables not updating correctly. Like this bit of code at the end of my sub. I reuse copyrng, lastrow, and lastcol from previous section.  When I debug, the lastrow and lastcol show the correct number but the copy range is only selecting column O (#15) down to the last row.  Any idea what is causing this or how to reset the variables?

```
With tbl3.DataBodyRange
CopyRng = .Range(Cells(1, 16), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol))

    With CopyRng
        .Copy
        Debug.Print .Address
        Debug.Print lastCol
    End With
```

End With

Comment: the first `Cells` is missing a dot in front of it